# Trying to format cells that have a value less than zero as comma

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test
    Dim s As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    s=11
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row
    Do Until s>lr
    If Cells(s,5).Value < 0 Then
        Cells(s,5).style = “comma”
        lr = lr -1
    Else
        s = s + 1
    End If
    Loop
End sub
```

This code is intended to change the first zero value it finds, and then it will stop. The values are in Column E and need to be have their styles changed but I  can't figure it out.

Comment: I suggest you scrap the `Do` loop and use a `For...Next` loop.

Comment: Like @BigBen said, `For each ... Next` is better for working with cells, `For i =... Next` is better for working with arrays/collections and `Do while/until` when working with files.

Comment: I believe it's possible without any loop at all, try using `ReplaceFormat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because if the value is less than 0 then `s` is never incremented. Also, not sure why you're decrementing `lr`? Move the increment code outside of your `if... then` statement and it should work.

```
Do Until s>lr
    If Cells(s,5).Value < 0 Then
        Cells(s,5).style = “comma”
    End If
    s = s + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Sub test
    Dim s As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    s=11
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row
    Do Until s>lr
         If Cells(s,5).Value < 0 Then Cells(s,5).style = “comma”
         s = s + 1
    Loop
End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would want to do it in one go without looping through all these cells, I believe the following would work, with:

***Sample data:***

[image]

***Code:***

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, lr As Long

With Application.ReplaceFormat
    .Clear
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("E11:E" & lr)
    rng.Replace What:="-*", Replacement:="", SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True
End With

End Sub
```

***Result:***

[image]

This would replace all the formatting on negative values in one go. Just check that the `.NumberFormat` does the same thing as the `.Style` as "comma" but I believe it does.

Comment: Thought something like this would be possible. Much better than looping.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As Long
    Dim lr As Long

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For s = 11 To lr
        If Cells(s, 5).Value < 0 Then 
            Cells(s, 5).Style = "comma" 
        End If        
    Next s
End Sub
```

Comment: you are missing an `End If` or a `_` after `Then`

Comment: You do not need the `s = 11` and `Dim i As Long` lines.